# Could a mail server be blocking a domain?

Tags: email, smtp

Weird question here. Could a mail server be blocking a domain?

I ask because i am in the process of migrating to a new server and i am testing out a few email accounts.

```
the domain x.com is hosted on server 1
the domain y.com is hosted on server 2
the domain z.com is hosted on server 2
```

If i email from x.com to y.com, the server replies with

```
550 sorry, no mailbox here by that name. (#5.7.17)
```

However, if i send from x.com to x.com also x.com to z.com they send fine.

y.com and z.com are on the server, so i don't see an issue with an IP block or anything like that.

Comment: I can confirm x.com, y.com and z.com email address I'm sending to all work fine on their own. Also if i email from x.com to my gmail account it works fine.

Comment: two possibilities: your code for sending from x.com to y.com is buggy (double check/post code), or they really are blocking the domain. It seems from the error message though that you just misspelled the account name (had they been blocking the domain, you just would have got a server not found or something similar).

Comment: I didn't write the code. both Horde and afterlogic webmail is throwing this error, also if i import the account into Apple Mail i still get the error. All accounts i sent the test to all exists and are spelt correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Generally this error happens when mail was hosted on the server at some point, but has since been moved to an external mail server. Qmail will still try to deliver the message locally and fail with this error:
>   This_address_no_longer_accepts_mail
>
> To correct this check the following two files for the domain in question:
>   /var/qmail/control/rcpthosts
>   /var/qmail/control/virtualdomains
>
> Remove the line with this domain from both files then restart Qmail:
>   /etc/init.d/qmail restart

From http://toastergremlin.com/?p=181